# Get static time of accomplished method Android

Tags: android, audio, android-audiomanager, android-music-player

Im working on music player for Android and I need to get static time to start playing music. Acutally command context.player.start() take random time from range <2;20> [ms] but I need to get static time of accomplishing method. My code is below.  I mean that time difference between "before call method time" and "just after method accomplished time" need to be static (method should take static time)

```
public class SpeakerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    MusicPlayer player;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_speaker);
        player = new MusicPlayer(SpeakerActivity.this);
        run();
    }

    private void run() {
       AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               ClientTask ct = new ClientTask(SpeakerActivity.this);
               try {
                   ct.run();
               } catch (IOException e1) {
                   e1.printStackTrace();
               }
           }

       });
    }

}


public class ClientTask extends Listener {

    ClientTask(Context context) { this.context = context);}

    ...


    //I'm only going to implement this method from Listener.class because I only need to use this one.
    public void received(Connection c, Object p){
        //Is the received packet the same class as PacketMessage.class?

        if(p instanceof PacketMessage){

            //Cast it, so we can access the message within.
            PacketMessage packet = (PacketMessage) p;


            if(packet.message.charAt(0) == 'p') {

                String latencyString = packet.message.replace('p','0');
                int latency = Integer.parseInt(latencyString);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(latency);
                    context.player.start(); <---- THIS LINE TAKE RANDOM AMOUNT OF TIME
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



            }
        }
    }


}


public class MusicPlayer {

    private MediaPlayer player;
    private Context context;

    public MusicPlayer(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        player = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.zero);
    }

    public void start() {
        player.start();
    }

    public void stop() {
        player.stop();
    }

}
```

Does anybody know whats wrong?

Comment: What is static time? What do you want, and what do you get instead? Reading your title it's totally unclear what you want. Do you want add a 0-20 ms delay? Or do you have a delay and you want to get rid of it? Please update the question

Comment: Okay, I just updated. Is it clear now?

Comment: you mean constant time?  Like it always executes in the same amount of time?   Or do you want it to execute faster so that it is more responsive?

Comment: Yes, I mean constant time. Its not nessesary to execute it faster or slower. I just need to get constant time of execution

Comment: I can't find a member or method called `player` in the class `Context`, so I'm surprised that line executes at all (or even compiles).  Where is `player` defined as a member of `Context`?